# Mongodb aggregate query very slow

Tags: mongodb, view, aggregate

I have a collection as below

Invoice

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("63b6d0483b21b4fd99352584"), 
    "DocumentType" : NumberInt(1), 
    "InOutInvoiceState" : "1", 
...
    "DocumentDiscountList" : [], 
    "DocumentDetailList" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("63b6d0483b21b4fd99352583"), 
            "ProductCode" : "60942", 
            "ProductVariantId" : null, 
            "Quantity" : 1.0, 
            "UoMId" : "624149652e722164e6965d23", 
            "UnitPrice" : 536.11, 
            "DetailDiscountList" : [], 
            "DiscountRate" : 0.0, 
            "DiscountAmount" : 0.0, 
            "VATList" : [
                {
                    "VATRate" : 8.0, 
                    "VATType" : "VAT", 
                    "VATAmount" : 42.8888, 
                    "VatExemptionReasonCode" : null, 
                    "VatExemptionReason" : null, 
                    "VatExemptionRate" : 0.0, 
                    "VatExemptionAmount" : 0.0, 
                    "VatExemptionId" : null
                }
            ], 
            "Amount" : 536.11, 
            "VATIncludeAmount" : 578.9988000000001, 
            "WarehouseId" : "623adc79561168fe30640403", 
            "LocationId" : "5c49be40dd9987f0ced2e25b", 
            "PriceDescriptionId" : "63170a2a572f174fc6e81c09", 
            "PriceDescriptionCurrency" : null, 
            "PriceDescriptionUnitPrice" : 0.0, 
            "SourceDocumentType" : "Order", 
            "SourceDetailId" : "63b431dbfa3cd85bc9edb15e", 
            "LotNo" : null
        }
    ], 
    "TotalAmount" : 536.11, 
    "TotalDiscountAmount" : 0.0, 
    "TotalVATAmount" : 42.89, 
    "TotalVATIncludeAmount" : 579.0, 
    "RecordInfo" : [], 
    "ExchangeRateList" : {},

...
}
```

I made a view to query the invoices,

```
db.InvoiceDocument.aggregate(
    [
        { 
            "$unwind" : { 
                "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays" : true, 
                "path" : "$DocumentDetailList"
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$lookup" : { 
                "as" : "DocumentDetailList.SendQuantity", 
                "from" : "WM_WaybillDetails_SendQuantity", 
                "localField" : "DocumentDetailList._id", 
                "foreignField" : "_id.SourceDetailObjId"
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$unwind" : { 
                "path" : "$DocumentDetailList.SendQuantity", 
                "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays" : true
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$addFields" : { 
                "DocumentDetailList2" : { 
                    "$mergeObjects" : [
                        "$DocumentDetailList.SendQuantity", 
                        "$DocumentDetailList"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$addFields" : { 
                "DocumentDetailList2.RemainingAmount" : { 
                    "$sum" : [
                        "$DocumentDetailList.Quantity", 
                        { 
                            "$multiply" : [
                                "$DocumentDetailList.SendQuantity.TotalQuantity", 
                                -1.0
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$lookup" : { 
                "from" : "Account", 
                "localField" : "AccountCode", 
                "foreignField" : "Code", 
                "as" : "AccountObj"
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$unwind" : { 
                "path" : "$AccountObj", 
                "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays" : true
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$addFields" : { 
                "DocumentTypeObjId" : { 
                    "$toObjectId" : "$DocumentTypeId"
                }
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$lookup" : { 
                "foreignField" : "_id", 
                "as" : "DocumentTypeObj", 
                "from" : "DocumentType", 
                "localField" : "DocumentTypeObjId"
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$unwind" : { 
                "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays" : true, 
                "path" : "$DocumentTypeObj"
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$addFields" : { 
                "SalesPersonObjId" : { 
                    "$toObjectId" : "$SalesPersonId"
                }
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$lookup" : { 
                "from" : "CompanyPerson", 
                "localField" : "SalesPersonObjId", 
                "foreignField" : "_id", 
                "as" : "SalesPersonObj"
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$unwind" : { 
                "path" : "$SalesPersonObj", 
                "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays" : true
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$addFields" : { 
                "PaymentTermsObjId" : { 
                    "$toObjectId" : "$PaymentTermsId"
                }
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$lookup" : { 
                "localField" : "PaymentTermsObjId", 
                "foreignField" : "_id", 
                "as" : "PaymentTermsObj", 
                "from" : "PaymentTerms"
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$unwind" : { 
                "path" : "$PaymentTermsObj", 
                "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays" : true
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$addFields" : { 
                "ShipmentTypeObjId" : { 
                    "$toObjectId" : "$ShipmentTypeId"
                }
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$lookup" : { 
                "foreignField" : "_id", 
                "as" : "ShipmentTypeObj", 
                "from" : "ShipmentType", 
                "localField" : "ShipmentTypeObjId"
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$unwind" : { 
                "path" : "$ShipmentTypeObj", 
                "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays" : true
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$lookup" : { 
                "from" : "Product", 
                "localField" : "DocumentDetailList2.ProductCode", 
                "foreignField" : "ProductCode", 
                "as" : "ProductObj"
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$unwind" : { 
                "path" : "$ProductObj", 
                "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays" : true
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$addFields" : { 
                "DocumentDetailList2.ProductName" : "$ProductObj.ProductName"
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$addFields" : { 
                "DocumentDetailList2.InvoiceProductName" : "$ProductObj.InvoiceProductName"
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$addFields" : { 
                "DocumentDetailList2.InvoiceProductCode" : "$ProductObj.InvoiceProductCode"
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$addFields" : { 
                "DocumentDetailList2.DMOProductCode" : "$ProductObj.DMOProductCode"
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$addFields" : { 
                "UoMObjId" : { 
                    "$toObjectId" : "$DocumentDetailList2.UoMId"
                }
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$lookup" : { 
                "from" : "UnitOfMeasure", 
                "localField" : "UoMObjId", 
                "foreignField" : "_id", 
                "as" : "UoMObj"
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$unwind" : { 
                "path" : "$UoMObj", 
                "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays" : true
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$addFields" : { 
                "DocumentDetailList2.UoMName" : "$UoMObj.UoMName"
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$addFields" : { 
                "DocumentDetailList2.EDocumentUOMCode" : "$UoMObj.EDocumentUOMCode"
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$addFields" : { 
                "PriceDescriptionObjId" : { 
                    "$toObjectId" : "$DocumentDetailList2.PriceDescriptionId"
                }
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$lookup" : { 
                "localField" : "PriceDescriptionObjId", 
                "foreignField" : "_id", 
                "as" : "PriceDescriptionObj", 
                "from" : "PriceDescription"
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$unwind" : { 
                "path" : "$PriceDescriptionObj", 
                "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays" : true
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$addFields" : { 
                "DocumentDetailList2.PriceDescriptionName" : "$PriceDescriptionObj.PriceName"
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$group" : { 
                "InvoiceDocumentTypeId" : { 
                    "$first" : "$InvoiceDocumentTypeId"
                }, 
                "DocumentDetailListGrp" : { 
                    "$push" : "$DocumentDetailList2"
                }, 
                "DocumentType" : { 
                    "$first" : "$DocumentType"
                }, 
                "InOutInvoiceState" : { 
                    "$first" : "$InOutInvoiceState"
                }, 
                "InvoiceDocumentNo" : { 
                    "$first" : "$InvoiceDocumentNo"
                }, 
                "PaymentTermsName" : { 
                    "$first" : "$PaymentTermsObj.PaymentTermsName"
                }, 
                "EDocumentSendId" : { 
                    "$first" : "$EDocumentSendId"
                }, 
                "EDocumentComment" : { 
                    "$first" : "$EDocumentComment"
                }, 
                "GibProfileId" : { 
                    "$first" : "$AccountObj.GibProfileId"
                }, 
                "SalesPersonName" : { 
                    "$first" : "$SalesPersonObj.PersonFullName"
                }, 
                "PaymentTermsId" : { 
                    "$first" : "$PaymentTermsId"
                }, 
                "InvoiceAddress" : { 
                    "$first" : "$InvoiceAddress"
                }, 
                "TermDay" : { 
                    "$first" : "$TermDay"
                }, 
                "AccountName" : { 
                    "$first" : "$AccountObj.Name"
                }, 
                "InvoiceAccountName" : { 
                    "$first" : "$InvoiceAccountName"
                }, 
                "CurrentCurrency" : { 
                    "$first" : "$CurrentCurrency"
                }, 
                "EDocumentNo" : { 
                    "$first" : "$EDocumentNo"
                }, 
                "PdfFileId" : { 
                    "$first" : "$PdfFileId"
                }, 
                "InvoiceDocumentDate" : { 
                    "$first" : "$InvoiceDocumentDate"
                }, 
                "InvoiceTaxAdministration" : { 
                    "$first" : "$InvoiceTaxAdministration"
                }, 
                "DeliveryPersonIdentityNo" : { 
                    "$first" : "$DeliveryPersonIdentityNo"
                }, 
                "SalesPersonId" : { 
                    "$first" : "$SalesPersonId"
                }, 
                "InvoiceOperationCurrency" : { 
                    "$first" : "$InvoiceOperationCurrency"
                }, 
                "InvoiceNote1" : { 
                    "$first" : "$InvoiceNote1"
                }, 
                "ShipmentTypeId" : { 
                    "$first" : "$ShipmentTypeId"
                }, 
                "InvoiceNote2" : { 
                    "$first" : "$InvoiceNote2"
                }, 
                "AccountSectionId" : { 
                    "$first" : "$AccountSectionId"
                }, 
                "TotalDiscountAmount" : { 
                    "$first" : "$TotalDiscountAmount"
                }, 
                "TotalVATIncludeAmount" : { 
                    "$first" : "$TotalVATIncludeAmount"
                }, 
                "DeliveryPersonName" : { 
                    "$first" : "$DeliveryPersonName"
                }, 
                "ShipmentTrackingNo" : { 
                    "$first" : "$ShipmentTrackingNo"
                }, 
                "ApprovalStatus" : { 
                    "$first" : "$ApprovalStatus"
                }, 
                "VatExceptionDesc" : { 
                    "$first" : "$VatExceptionDesc"
                }, 
                "TotalRemaining" : { 
                    "$sum" : { 
                        "$cond" : { 
                            "if" : { 
                                "$lte" : [
                                    "$DocumentDetailList2.RemainingAmount", 
                                    0.0
                                ]
                            }, 
                            "then" : 0.0, 
                            "else" : "$DocumentDetailList2.RemainingAmount"
                        }
                    }
                }, 
                "CurrentExchangeRate" : { 
                    "$first" : "$CurrentExchangeRate"
                }, 
                "IsActive" : { 
                    "$first" : "$IsActive"
                }, 
                "_id" : { 
                    "InvoiceID" : "$_id"
                }, 
                "InvoiceTaxNumber" : { 
                    "$first" : "$InvoiceTaxNumber"
                }, 
                "TotalVATAmount" : { 
                    "$first" : "$TotalVATAmount"
                }, 
                "ShipmentCompanyId" : { 
                    "$first" : "$ShipmentCompanyId"
                }, 
                "DocumentTypeId" : { 
                    "$first" : "$DocumentTypeId"
                }, 
                "InvoiceOperationExchangeRate" : { 
                    "$first" : "$InvoiceOperationExchangeRate"
                }, 
                "VatExceptionCode" : { 
                    "$first" : "$VatExceptionCode"
                }, 
                "TotalOrderQuantity" : { 
                    "$sum" : "$DocumentDetailList2.Quantity"
                }, 
                "AccountCode" : { 
                    "$first" : "$AccountCode"
                }, 
                "TotalAmount" : { 
                    "$first" : "$TotalAmount"
                }, 
                "DocumentTypeName" : { 
                    "$first" : "$DocumentTypeObj.DocumentTypeName"
                }, 
                "CSOrderNo" : { 
                    "$first" : "$CSOrderNo"
                }, 
                "ShipmentTypeName" : { 
                    "$first" : "$ShipmentTypeObj.ShipmentTypeName"
                }, 
                "EDocumentId" : { 
                    "$first" : "$EDocumentId"
                }
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$project" : { 
                "EDocumentComment" : { 
                    "$ifNull" : [
                        "$EDocumentComment", 
                        ""
                    ]
                }, 
                "DocumentType" : "$DocumentType", 
...
                "DocumentStateName" : { 
                    "$cond" : { 
                        "if" : { 
                            "$or" : [
                                { 
                                    "$eq" : [
                                        "$DocumentType", 
                                        3.0
                                    ]
                                }, 
                                { 
                                    "$eq" : [
                                        "$DocumentType", 
                                        4.0
                                    ]
                                }, 
                                { 
                                    "$eq" : [
                                        "$DocumentType", 
                                        7.0
                                    ]
                                }, 
                                { 
                                    "$eq" : [
                                        "$DocumentType", 
                                        8.0
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }, 
                        "then" : { 
                            "$cond" : { 
                                "if" : { 
                                    "$lte" : [
                                        "$TotalRemaining", 
                                        0.0
                                    ]
                                }, 
                                "then" : "invoiced waybill", 
                                "else" : "waybill"
                            }
                        }, 
                        "else" : "İnvoice"
                    }
                }, 
                "AccountName" : "$AccountName", 
 ...
                "DocumentState" : { 
                    "$cond" : { 
                        "if" : { 
                            "$or" : [
                                { 
                                    "$eq" : [
                                        "$DocumentType", 
                                        3.0
                                    ]
                                }, 
                                { 
                                    "$eq" : [
                                        "$DocumentType", 
                                        4.0
                                    ]
                                }, 
                                { 
                                    "$eq" : [
                                        "$DocumentType", 
                                        7.0
                                    ]
                                }, 
                                { 
                                    "$eq" : [
                                        "$DocumentType", 
                                        8.0
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }, 
                        "then" : { 
                            "$cond" : { 
                                "if" : { 
                                    "$lte" : [
                                        "$TotalRemaining", 
                                        0.0
                                    ]
                                }, 
                                "then" : 3.0, 
                                "else" : 1.0
                            }
                        }, 
                        "else" : 2.0
                    }
                }, 
                "_id" : "$_id.InvoiceID", 
                "AccountCode" : "$AccountCode", 
                "EDocumentId" : "$EDocumentId", 
                "DocumentTypeName" : "$DocumentTypeName", 
                "InvoiceNote1" : "$InvoiceNote1", 
                "InvoiceTaxAdministration" : "$InvoiceTaxAdministration", 
                "TotalDiscountAmount" : "$TotalDiscountAmount", 
                "ShipmentTypeName" : "$ShipmentTypeName", 
                "DocumentDetailListVM" : "$DocumentDetailListGrp"
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$sort" : { 
                "InvoiceDocumentDate" : -1.0
            }
        }
    ], 
    { 
        "allowDiskUse" : false
    }
);
```

WM_WaybillDetails_SendQuantity view

```
db.InvoiceDocument.aggregate(
    [
        { 
            "$match" : { 
                "DocumentDetailList.SourceDocumentType" : "Waybill"
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$unwind" : { 
                "path" : "$DocumentDetailList", 
                "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays" : true
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$addFields" : { 
                "SourceDetailObjId" : { 
                    "$toObjectId" : "$DocumentDetailList.SourceDetailId"
                }
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$group" : { 
                "TotalQuantity" : { 
                    "$sum" : "$DocumentDetailList.Quantity"
                }, 
                "_id" : { 
                    "SourceDetailObjId" : "$SourceDetailObjId"
                }
            }
        }
    ], 
    { 
        "allowDiskUse" : false
    }
);
```

When I run the query for the view, the result is very slow, the reason is that I do not merge with another view in the first lookup. But I need to do that merge, I need to get the result in a single view like this.

```
 "stages" : [
        { 
            "$cursor" : { 
                "queryPlanner" : { 
                    "namespace" : "InvoiceDocument", 
                    "indexFilterSet" : false, 
                    "parsedQuery" : { 

                    }, 
                    "queryHash" : "", 
                    "planCacheKey" : "", 
                    "maxIndexedOrSolutionsReached" : false, 
                    "maxIndexedAndSolutionsReached" : false, 
                    "maxScansToExplodeReached" : false, 
                    "winningPlan" : { 
                        "stage" : "PROJECTION_DEFAULT", 
                        "transformBy" : { 
                            "AccountCode" : NumberInt(1), 
                           ...
                        }, 
                        "inputStage" : { 
                            "stage" : "COLLSCAN", 
                            "direction" : "forward"
                        }
                    }, 
                    "rejectedPlans" : [

                    ]
                }, 
                "executionStats" : { 
                    "executionSuccess" : true, 
                    "nReturned" : NumberInt(997), 
                    "executionTimeMillis" : NumberInt(6177), 
                    "totalKeysExamined" : NumberInt(0), 
                    "totalDocsExamined" : NumberInt(997), 
                    "executionStages" : { 
                        "stage" : "PROJECTION_DEFAULT", 
                        "nReturned" : NumberInt(997), 
                        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : NumberInt(0), 
                        "works" : NumberInt(999), 
                        "advanced" : NumberInt(997), 
                        "needTime" : NumberInt(1), 
                        "needYield" : NumberInt(0), 
                        "saveState" : NumberInt(1), 
                        "restoreState" : NumberInt(1), 
                        "isEOF" : NumberInt(1), 
                        "transformBy" : { 
                            "AccountCode" : NumberInt(1), 
                            ...
                        }, 
                        "inputStage" : { 
                            "stage" : "COLLSCAN", 
                            "nReturned" : NumberInt(997), 
                            "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : NumberInt(0), 
                            "works" : NumberInt(999), 
                            "advanced" : NumberInt(997), 
                            "needTime" : NumberInt(1), 
                            "needYield" : NumberInt(0), 
                            "saveState" : NumberInt(1), 
                            "restoreState" : NumberInt(1), 
                            "isEOF" : NumberInt(1), 
                            "direction" : "forward", 
                            "docsExamined" : NumberInt(997)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }, 
            "nReturned" : NumberLong(997), 
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : NumberLong(0)
        }, 
{ 
            "$unwind" : { 
                "path" : "$DocumentDetailList", 
                "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays" : true
            }, 
            "nReturned" : NumberLong(1499), 
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : NumberLong(0)
        }, 
        { 
            "$lookup" : { 
                "from" : "WM_WaybillDetails_SendQuantity", 
                "as" : "DocumentDetailList.SendQuantity", 
                "localField" : "DocumentDetailList._id", 
                "foreignField" : "_id.SourceDetailObjId", 
                "unwinding" : { 
                    "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays" : true
                }
            }, 
            "totalDocsExamined" : NumberLong(1494503), 
            "totalKeysExamined" : NumberLong(0), 
            "collectionScans" : NumberLong(2998), 
            "indexesUsed" : [

            ], 
            "nReturned" : NumberLong(1499), 
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : NumberLong(966)
        },
```

When I examined the above, I saw that the lookup connection to another view is slow, when I run the second view alone, it works fast, but when I use it in this way, it returns very slow data,
How else can I write this view?
Thanks

Comment: Your query against the `WM_WaybillDetails_SendQuantity` view to get a single matching `_id`is going to be slow as the database has to compute the result of that entire view before it can filter for the document that you want. More broadly, your against suggest that you've taken a normalized schema from an RDBMS and used it directly in MongoDB. It may result in it being very difficult to return with. I'd suggest transforming the data into a model/schema more appropriate for the database that you're using which should make all future interactions much easier

Comment: You may review your data design. NoSQL databases like MongoDB are not optimized for joins (i.e. $lookup), some of them even do not support joins at all. It is a common mistake to migrate tables from relational RDBMS to collections in MongoDB database one-by-one. Usually a MongoDB database has much less number of collections than according application has tables in relational database.